# pop-theme causes gnome-control-center segmentation fault

Tags: gnome, segmentation-fault, gnome-control-center

Ubuntu 19.10
Gnome 3.28

I'm trying to run `gnome-control-center`

Result:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

- Clear gnome-control-center .cache and .config
- Remove all gnome extensions
- Installed all the updates
- Reboot

nothing changed...

```
     > coredumpctl info:

          PID: 12246 (gnome-control-c)
          UID: 1000 (michaeldl)
          GID: 1000 (michaeldl)
       Signal: 11 (SEGV)
    Timestamp: Sun 2019-11-10 23:23:21 MSK (1h 6min ago)
 Command Line: gnome-control-center
   Executable: /usr/bin/gnome-control-center
Control Group: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/gnome-shell-x11.service
         Unit: user@1000.service
    User Unit: gnome-shell-x11.service
        Slice: user-1000.slice
    Owner UID: 1000 (michaeldl)
      Boot ID: 4a24792e63014ae2904ad4e50987a50c
   Machine ID: ef03f98c351a4bb19f7d0ca6b14695c6
     Hostname: michaeldl
      Storage: /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.gnome-control-c.1000.4a24792e63014ae2904ad4e50987a50c.12246.1573417401000000.lz4
   Message: Process 12246 (gnome-control-c) of user 1000 dumped core.

            Stack trace of thread 12246:
            #0  0x00007f34a3155e1e gtk_container_add (libgtk-3.so.0)
            #1  0x000055c367493ba5 n/a (gnome-control-center)
            #2  0x00007f34a3830546 n/a (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
            #3  0x00007f34a3832278 g_object_new_valist (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
            #4  0x00007f34a38325cd g_object_new (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
            #5  0x000055c367452676 n/a (gnome-control-center)
            #6  0x00007f34a382d7ef g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__STRINGv (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
            #7  0x00007f34a382a936 n/a (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
            #8  0x00007f34a384736c g_signal_emit_valist (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
            #9  0x00007f34a38479b3 g_signal_emit (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
            #10 0x000055c367450787 n/a (gnome-control-center)
            #11 0x00007f34a382dde3 g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__OBJECTv (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
            #12 0x00007f34a382a936 n/a (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
            #13 0x00007f34a384736c g_signal_emit_valist (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
            #14 0x00007f34a38479b3 g_signal_emit (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
            #15 0x00007f34a382a936 n/a (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
            #16 0x00007f34a384736c g_signal_emit_valist (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
            #17 0x00007f34a3847fa9 g_signal_emit_by_name (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
            #18 0x000055c367450f49 cc_panel_list_set_active_panel (gnome-control-center)
            #19 0x000055c36745316f n/a (gnome-control-center)
            #20 0x00007f34a3830546 n/a (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
            #21 0x00007f34a3832278 g_object_new_valist (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
            #22 0x00007f34a38325cd g_object_new (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
            #23 0x000055c3674535ac cc_window_new (gnome-control-center)
            #24 0x000055c36744cfc3 n/a (gnome-control-center)
            #25 0x00007f34a382a936 n/a (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
            #26 0x00007f34a384736c g_signal_emit_valist (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
            #27 0x00007f34a38479b3 g_signal_emit (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
            #28 0x00007f34a3952312 g_application_register (libgio-2.0.so.0)
            #29 0x00007f34a39526ee n/a (libgio-2.0.so.0)
            #30 0x00007f34a3952a72 g_application_run (libgio-2.0.so.0)
            #31 0x000055c36744c639 main (gnome-control-center)
            #32 0x00007f34a15c71e3 __libc_start_main (libc.so.6)
            #33 0x000055c36744c84e _start (gnome-control-center)

            Stack trace of thread 12255:
```

Any ideas?..

**UPD:**
Remove gnome-control-center with dependencies and install it again...
Nothing changed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion there is a much better solution to that problem other than getting rid of a useful repository I personally like.
What helped me is fixing the main repo priority.
You may see that there are two repositories available for `gnome-control-center` package and the system76 is used now using a `apt-cache policy gnome-control-center` command:

```
gnome-control-center:
  Installed: 1:3.34.1-1ubuntu2pop1~1571679625~19.10~ef2ab1f
  Candidate: 1:3.34.1-1ubuntu2pop1~1571679625~19.10~ef2ab1f
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.34.1-1ubuntu2pop1~1571679625~19.10~ef2ab1f 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:3.34.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
```

See those `500`s? That's the default repo priority and it's the same.
Let's give the main repo a higher priority (I'm on Ubuntu 19.10 codename `eoan`, 
 please use your distro's codename instead):

```
    $ apt-cache policy | grep o=Ubuntu | grep c=main | grep a=eoan,
     release v=19.10,o=Ubuntu,a=eoan,n=eoan,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     release v=19.10,o=Ubuntu,a=eoan,n=eoan,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
```

That `release ...` part is kind of a filter you may use to give a repo different priority. Create and edit (as a root) a file called `/etc/apt/preferences.d/main_repo_priority` to look like this:

```
    Package: *
    Pin: release v=19.10,o=Ubuntu,a=eoan,n=eoan,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
    Pin-Priority: 1001
```

And now finally reinstall the `gnome-control-center`:

```
    sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

And double check that the correct version is installed:

```
    $ apt-cache policy gnome-control-center
     gnome-control-center:
       Installed: 1:3.34.1-1ubuntu2
       Candidate: 1:3.34.1-1ubuntu2
       Version table:
          1:3.34.1-1ubuntu2pop1~1571679625~19.10~ef2ab1f 500
             500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu eoan/main amd64                                                          Packages
     *** 1:3.34.1-1ubuntu2 1001
           1001 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Yes. This solution is better. thx @ViacheslavRodionov

Answer (score 2):

I fix it.
I have third party repository `ppa:system76/pop`
It was added during `pop-theme` installation.
After update `gnome-control-center` from `system76/pop` replace original `gnome-control-center`.

What I've done:

- remove `pop-theme`
- remove system76/pop repository and GPG key from `/etc/apt/*`
- remove apt cache
- remove broken `gnome-control-center` from system76/pop
- install original `gnome-control-center`

Now everything is working fine.