# Gnome control center not opening

Tags: gnome, system-settings

Recently ,after installing and then removing pop os theme ,Ubuntu settings no longer opens .
ERROR in terminal I get is

```
(gnome-control-center:12426): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: : Settings schema 'org.gnome.shell.extensions.pop-shell' is not installed
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

I also  removed pop os theme repositories ,keys

Comment: if you removed the POP OS repo, you can try with the command "sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center"

Comment: Anyhow, in POP OS repo there is an explicit message: "WARNING: This PPA is for Pop!_OS, and it may cause breakage on other Ubuntu-based OS's. Use of this repository on non-Pop_OS installations is at your own risk!" What happened is that, during an update, your original gnome.control-center was replaced by the POP OS one, causing your troubles.

Comment: Already done that , I get same error

Comment: Check if this will help you (the official solution is not applicable in ypour case, I suppose): https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187809/pop-theme-causes-gnome-control-center-segmentation-fault

Comment: I tried this , it seems to worked  https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset GNOME to the defaults?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults)